# How do I animate a svg circle with css

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm trying to animate a circle in a svg graphic to increase in size around its own centre point.

Here is my svg:

```
<svg version="1.1" class="p-svg-pulse" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 80 80" enable-background="new 0 0 80 80" xml:space="preserve">
    <circle class="pulse" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="40" cy="40" r="10"/>
    <circle class="halo" fill="none" stroke="#FF9C00" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="40" cy="40" r="21"/>
    <circle class="center" fill="#FF9C00" cx="40" cy="40" r="12"/>
</svg>
```

I've tried animating scale, which works, but then I can't get the centre point to stay put.

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzyvagina/xaoknoaj/)

PS. I'm trying to not use js for this problem, because it would add a lot of unnecessary complexity to my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incase anyone else is interested, I ended up solving the issue by using a matrix transform and animating the stroke width to maintain approximate size.

```
@-webkit-keyframes svg_pulse {
     0% {
        -webkit-transform: matrix(1,0,01,0,0);
        stroke-width: 1;
        opacity: 1;
     }

     50% {
        opacity: 1;
     }
     100% {
        -webkit-transform: matrix(4,0,0,4,-120,-120);
        stroke-width: 0.25;
        opacity: 0;
     }
}

.p-svg-pulse .pulse {
    -webkit-animation: svg_pulse 3s ease;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzyvagina/xaoknoaj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) to supply a centre point for the scaling.

Alternatively wrap each circle in a g that translates by cx, cy it and remove the circle cx and cy attributes so that each circle is drawn around its local origin.